# How to access underlying COM object of a managed .NET object created using TLBIMP

Tags: c#, com, com-interop

I have a number of COM libraries which I need to access from a WF4 activity, so I used `tlbimp` to generate managed wrappers for them. This works fine, but in a couple of cases there is a COM method which expects an array of Variants as one of its arguments, and one of the elements of the array is an instance of a COM class from another DLL, which I can't see how to get a reference to even though I have a reference to a managed wrapper representing the same object.

As an example, say I have two COM libraries called `ABC` and `DEF`, for which I have created managed wrappers called `ABCManaged` and `DEFManaged` using `tlbimp`. Say that `DEF` has a method with the following signature (forgive the VB-style signature, that's the way it is in the documentation):

```vb
CallFunction (parmArray() as Variant) as Long
```

This gets represented in `DEFManaged` as follows:

```cs
int CallFunction(ref object parmArray)
```

So far so good. Now, the elements of the array of Variants which is the argument to `CallFunction()` are of different types, so in my case the first element is a `double` and the second one is an instance of `ABC`. Here's how I am building up my array to pass to my managed `CallFunction()`:

```cs
// obtain our managed ABC from the workflow context
ABCManaged abc = context.GetValue(this.InputABC);
object[] parameters =  new object[2];
parameters[0] = new double();
parameters[1] = abc;

DEFManaged def = new DEFManaged();
def.CallFunction(parameters);
```

This compiles fine, but does not work - the call to `CallFunction()` throws this exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

My guess is that `def` is not getting marshaled correctly to the underlying unmanaged `DEF` type, probably because the signature simply has an array of `object`, and the logic which determines the real types of the array's elements is somewhere in the implementation of the COM method `CallFunction()`. I can't figure out how to manually marshal my `def` object to an unmanaged `DEF` type before sticking it into the array to pass to my managed `CallFunction()`.

Using straight P/Invoke is not an option here either; I can certainly write the code, but one of the requirements is that users of the WF4 activity be able to access properties and methods on `DEFManaged` objects, so they need to be managed objects.

Comment: The object seems to get marshalled to the com server correctly. Otherwise another exception would be thrown, most likely a `InvalidComObjectException` or another `COMException`. The `ArgumentException` get's thrown by the server's implementation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ztbc5s1.aspx

Comment: Well, `object[]` is being correctly marshaled to `Variant()`, but my guess is that the actual elements in the array are not correctly marshaled because the interface doesn't know it has to do so, because the signatures of neither the COM object nor its managed equivalent specify the types of the array elements. 

Do you think this guess is wrong and that the second element of my array (a `ManagedABC` object in my example) is being correctly marshaled to the underlying COM object (a `DEF` object in my example), despite the interface not specifying that type?

Comment: I was mistaken about what was happening here: the individual objects in the array were being marshaled correctly, but the array itself was being passed by value instead of by reference (the COM object required it to be passed by reference). See answer below for details on how this was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the individual objects in the array were being marshaled correctly, but the array itself was being passed by value instead of by reference (the COM object required it to be passed by reference - `VT_BYREF`). This surfaced when I was able to attach a debugger to the COM object.

It's not straightforward to pass an array by reference from C# to COM. I initially worked around this by having an intermediate proxy COM object in VB6 (!) which didn't require passing by reference, and calling the original COM object from my proxy object (VB6 always passes by reference).

This was not ideal, but it also turns out that it is possible to force C# to pass arguments to a COM method by reference using late binding via reflection and a [ParameterModifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parametermodifier(v=vs.100).aspx), as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15229618/533676) to [my question on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15216951/how-to-pass-an-array-from-c-sharp-to-unmanaged-com-by-reference-vt-byref).

Here is the way it works:

```
// obtain our managed ABC from the workflow context
ABCManaged abc = context.GetValue(this.InputABC);

object[] parameters =  new object[2]; // method argument, i.e. parmArray value
parameters[0] = new double();
parameters[1] = abc;

DEFManaged d = new DEFManaged(); // managed wrapper for our COM object

var t = typeof(DEFManaged);
object[] args = new object[1]; // array which will contain all method arguments
args[0] = data; // data is the first argument, i.e. first element of args array

ParameterModifier[] pms = new ParameterModifier[1];
ParameterModifier pm = new ParameterModifier(1);
pm[0] = true; // pass the 1st argument by reference
pms[0] = pm;  // add pm to the array of modifiers 

// invoke CallFunction by name via IDispatch interface
var ret = t.InvokeMember("CallFunction", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, d, args, pms, null, null);
Console.Out.WriteLine("Result = " + ret);
```

As suggested in the original answer, I made this into a extension method on the `DEFManaged` interface, so users of the managed wrapper can simply call the extension method directly and it handles the reflection for them.