# How to pass an array from C# to unmanaged COM by reference (VT_BYREF)

Tags: c#, com, interop, marshalling, com-interop

I have a COM component written in C++ whose source I can't change, and one of the arguments to one of its methods is `VARIANT *pParamArray`. Using `tlbimp` I can create a managed stub for it and pass it an array from C#.

Unfortunately, the COM component is expecting its array to be passed by reference - there's an explicit check for `pParamArray->vt != (VT_BYREF | VT_ARRAY | VT_VARIANT)` and it returns an error if it doesn't pass that check.

I have the PDB and source for the COM component, so I'm debugging both the C# and the unmanaged code in tandem. I can see that my C# array of `object[]` is being passed as `VT_ARRAY | VT_VARIANT`, which is essentially a `SAFEARRAY` as far as I understand it.

How can I explicitly tell C# that I want to pass it by reference, so that the type on the far end has the `VT_BYREF` mask?

- I've tried putting it in a `VariantWrapper` - I get an `ArgumentException` with the message "`VariantWrappers cannot be stored in Variants.`"
- I've tried doing a `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` and using `Marshal.GetNativeVariantForObject()` but I only get an `int` on the COM end.

`tlbimp` by default marshals the parameter in question as `UnmanagedType.Struct`. I'm not sure how to make `tlbimp` marshal it as `IntPtr`, or even if this would make a difference (I also tried using the enhanced `tlbimp2` from CodePlex, but it doesn't seem to recognize my request for `IntPtr` in its config file).

I'm by no means an Interop expert so feel free to suggest something which may appear obvious to you.

### Update 1

As requested by @ZdeslavVojkovic, here are relevant pieces of the IDL:

```cpp
[
    uuid(01234567-89AB-CDEF-0123-3456789ABCDE),
    version(1.0),
    helpstring("XXX")
]
library LAbc
{
    [
        object,
        uuid(01234567-89AB-CDEF-0123-3456789ABCDE),
        dual,
        helpstring("XXX"),
        pointer_default(unique)
    ]
    interface IAbc : IDispatch
    {
            [id(1), helpstring("XXX")]
            HRESULT CallFunction([in] myEnum Function, [in, out] VARIANT* pParamArray, [out, retval] long* pVal);
    };

    [
        uuid(01234567-89AB-CDEF-0123-3456789ABCDE),
        helpstring("XXXs")
    ]
    coclass Abc
    {
        [default] interface IAbc;
    };
};
```

And here is the method signature itself and the internal check for the parameter's type:

```cpp
STDMETHODIMP XAbc::CallFunction(myEnum Function, VARIANT *pParamArray, long *pVal)
{
    ...

    // we must get a pointer to an array of variants
    if(!pParamArray ||
        (pParamArray->vt != (VT_BYREF | VT_ARRAY | VT_VARIANT)) ||
        !(psa = *pParamArray->pparray))
        return E_INVALIDARG;

    ...
}
```

Comment: can you show the exact definition of the interface and signature of the method?

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic Added relevant pieces of the IDL, the signature, and how I'm calling it in my question above.

Comment: I believe that this is not possible without rewriting the marshaling info in the generated interop dll. If you would rewrite to declare the array as `IntPtr` instead of `ref object`, then it can be made to work

Comment: I ditched `TLBIMP` and wrote the interop code myself. Even when I declare the array as `IntPtr` and manually marshaled the array into an `IntPtr` before calling the method, it _still_ comes out the far end as `VT_ARRAY | VT_VARIANT`, not `VT_BYREF | VT_ARRAY | VT_VARIANT`.

Totally stumped here - next step is to try making a C++ wrapper and calling that from C# instead (as suggested by @jacob-seleznev below.

Comment: yup, same thing here with modified interop IL...

Comment: got it by using late binding, please see the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to make it work without rewriting the IL.

Please note that for simplicity I have skipped the enum param so IDL definition of the method is like this:

```
[
    object,
    uuid(E2375DCC-8B5B-4BD3-9F6A-A9C1F8BD8300),
    dual,
    helpstring("IDummy Interface"),
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface IDummy : IDispatch
{
    [id(1)] HRESULT Fn([in, out] VARIANT *pParamArray, [out, retval]long *pVal);
};
```

You can call it by late binding call like this:

```
INTEROPXLib.IDummy d = new INTEROPXLib.DummyClass();

object data = new object[3]; // method argument, i.e. pParamArray value

var t = typeof(INTEROPXLib.IDummy);
object[] args = new object[1]; // array which will contain all method arguments
args[0] = data; // data is the first argument, i.e. first element of args array

ParameterModifier[] pms = new ParameterModifier[1];
ParameterModifier pm = new ParameterModifier(1);
pm[0] = true; // pass the 1st argument by reference
pms[0] = pm;  // add pm to the array of modifiers 

// invoke Fn by name via IDispatch interface
var ret = t.InvokeMember("Fn", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, d, args, pms, null, null);
Console.Out.WriteLine("Result = " + ret);
```

For convenience, it would be better to wrap this into an extension method on the interface.

Comment: Excellent stuff - I had already made an intermediate proxy COM object  but this appears to work really well and is cleaner. I wrote an extension method on the interface as you suggested - makes the API very clean.