# Passing a c# array of object to COM interface method

Tags: c#, c++, com, marshalling

I should pass a pointer of object array to a COM interface with the following IDL and C++ definitions:
C++ code:

```
UpdateItem( LONG lID, LONG lNumOfFields, FieldIdEnum* pFields, VARIANT* pvValues )
```

IDL:

```
HRESULT UpdateItem( [in] LONG lID, [in] LONG lNumOfFields, [in, size_is(lNumOfFields)] FieldIdEnum* pFields, [in, size_is(lNumOfFields)] VARIANT* pvValues );
```

tlbimp generated C# code:

```
UpdateItem([In] int lID, [In] int lNumOfFields, [In] ref FieldIdEnum pFields, [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref object pvValues);
```

... and I try to call with:

```
FieldIdEnum[] fieldIDs = { FieldIdEnum.fi1ID, FieldIdEnum.fi2At };
object[] values = { 3, DateTime.UtcNow };
mi.UpdateItem(1, 2, ref fieldIDs[0], ref values[0]);
```

I get this interface from my system as result of login and authentication process... The UpdateItem method is a public member of that interface.

I want to pass two or more field and value pairs (in same time) by the two array.
The field array always is passed correctly to C++ code. I have debugged C++ code and the "FieldIdEnum* pFields" represents the first element of an integer array and the 2nd element (pFields[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15216951/how-to-pass-an-array-from-c-sharp-to-unmanaged-com-by-reference-vt-byref)) is correct too. The pField[] is a c-style array.

But the 2nd array is a variant array with various element type in this case an integer and a date time. This appears as a SafeArray at c++ side instead of c_style array. I have checked this 2nd array too, it is a simple variant array if the method calling starts from another C code, but C# tries to marshal it to safearray.

I have changed the C# definition to

```
UpdateItem([In] int lID, [In] int lNumOfFields, [In] ref FieldIdEnum pFields, [In] ref object pvValues);
```

It does not work I always get an exception like "Value does not fall within the expected range."    "System.Exception {System.ArgumentException}"

I have tried to use/marshal various managed/unmanaged types and Intptr, did not work.

I have found an [other topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15216951/how-to-pass-an-array-from-c-sharp-to-unmanaged-com-by-reference-vt-byref) with same/similar problem, I could not make it work.

How should I pass a pointer of object array to COM interface?

Comment: Do you have control over the interface?  `SAFEARRAY` will automatically work in managed code.  Bit more of a bear from native, though.  Otherwise, I expect you would have to pin an array of `IntPtr` manually filled with `Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject` and pass that address.  I'm not sure what the marshalling for `object[]` is with `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]`.

Comment: Just pass an [In] VARIANT* parameter when you want to pass an array, and remove your `size_is` attribute in idl (more for C-style non-Automation interface). From .NET then use an object[] of anything as input.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change the COM/IDL code because it is used in other C/C++/Delphi application...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the solution.
I have redefined the interface method:

```
        void UpdateItem([In] int lID, [In] int lNumOfFields, [In] ref FieldIdEnum pFields, [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] object[] pvValues);
```

... and call this as:

```
            FieldIdEnum[] updateFieldIDs = { FieldIdEnum.fi1ID, FieldIdEnum.fi2At };
            object[] values = { 3, DateTime.UtcNow };
            
            mi.UpdateItem(id, updateFieldIDs.Length, ref updateFieldIDs[0], values);
```

Thank you for guidance.